# Is my CSS padding displaying incorrectly? Or have I got my syntax wrong?

Tags: css, padding

I'm setting padding values for `h1` and `p` in css as follows:

```
h1 {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
p {
    padding-left: 33px;
    padding-right: 135px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

But there seems to be some form of preformatted padding in the table they are used in because the top shows up indent padded by about 30px, when there is none in the table's css. What am I doing wrong? Here's an image to explain what I mean:

[image: 1] [example]

The padding above "Title" is nowhere in my code.

Thanks, 
Oliver

Comment: Try setting `margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;` on your H1 element.

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing the html and more of the css. It could just be the browser's default stylesheet.

Comment: Did you say a table? Can we see your markup?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use padding?  Paddings do not collapse, but margins do:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might need to reset default margins on the `h1` element

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML a `h1` tag has a default margin, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

You would probably be best taking the default margin off the h1 using:

```
h1{
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to avoid this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `table` then you need to set your vertical alignment for your `td` to top, rather than the default which is `middle`

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```